# Name useState's current state after the initial state, but with the current state value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

As you can see below, I'm calling the **isChecked** prop from the `<Todo/>` parent component. I need to change it's value depending on the user's click, so I'm using 'useState' and setting up an event. The problem is that I can't send it to the API named as **currentCheck**, it needs to be named **isChecked** again so my API can recognize and save the new value.

Obs: I'm new to React and I'm just training, so this may be a silly question, sry.

```
function Todo({ _id, text, isChecked }) {
   const [currentCheck, setCurrentCheck] = useState(isChecked),
         [icon, setIcon] = useState(ellipseOutline)

    async function handleClick() {
        if (currentCheck) {
            setCurrentCheck(false)
            setIcon(ellipseOutline)
            return await api.put('/', { _id, currentCheck })
        }

        setCurrentCheck(true)
        setIcon(checkmarkCircle)
        return await api.put('/', { _id, currentCheck })
    }
```

Comment: You can name the key in the anonymous object. `return await api.put('/', { _id, isChecked: currentCheck })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your question.  Your API request looks like `{_id: 1, isChecked: true}` and you need `isChecked` attribute instead of `currentCheck`.

You can do it in this way

```js
function Todo({ _id, text, isChecked }) {
   const [currentCheck, setCurrentCheck] = useState(isChecked),
         [icon, setIcon] = useState(ellipseOutline)

    async function handleClick() {
        if (currentCheck) {
            setCurrentCheck(false)
            setIcon(ellipseOutline)
            return await api.put('/', { _id, isChecked : currentCheck })
        }

        setCurrentCheck(true)
        setIcon(checkmarkCircle)
        return await api.put('/', { _id, isChecked : currentCheck })
    }
```

This can also be written as

```js
function Todo({ _id, text, isChecked }) {
   const [currentCheck, setCurrentCheck] = useState(isChecked),
         [icon, setIcon] = useState(ellipseOutline)

    async function handleClick() {
        setCurrentCheck((prevState) => !prevState);
        setIcon(() => currentCheck ? ellipseOutline : checkmarkCircle);
        return await api.put('/', { _id, isChecked : currentCheck })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should write your code as below :

```
function Todo({ _id, text, isChecked }) {
     const [currentCheck, setCurrentCheck] = useState(isChecked),
                [icon, setIcon] = useState(ellipseOutline)

     async function handleClick() {
          if (currentCheck) {
              setCurrentCheck(preve => !preve)
              setIcon(ellipseOutline)
              return await api.put('/', { _id, isChecked: currentCheck })
          }
          setCurrentCheck(preve => !preve)
          setIcon(checkmarkCircle)
          return await api.put('/', { _id, isChecked: currentCheck })
     }
```

Please test it and write your feedback in comment

Comment: Actually the problem is in the fact that I'm passing something named "currentCheck" instead of "isChecked" to the API. How can I pass the currentCheck value to something named isChecked and send to the API?